# Pronuncia di "praticamente"

Tags: regional, pronunciation, colloquial

A Roma "praticamente", quando significa "in pratica", spesso nel parlato viene pronunciato come "praente" o "preente" o con una vocale molto lunga che alterna tra a ed e. Succede anche fuori da Roma? E conoscete altri casi simili?

Ho trovato casualmente un esempio in un video, al secondo 7 :D spero si veda

https://www.instagram.com/tv/CJqMszuoeTZ/?igshid=1vhxidol21m9i

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Curioso: quindi, se ho capito bene, i fonemi corrispondenti a [ticam] spariscono completamente?

Comment: E questa vocale molto lunga sarebbe il fonema [ə] allungato (geminato?)?

Comment: Sì, spariscono, non è obbligatorio chiaro, è una variante della pronuncia normale ma nella lingua di tutti i giorni è molto più diffusa. Anche "praamente" è possibile. Non c'è uno schwa ma c'è o /ae/ o /ee/ o una specie di /aeae/, cerco di riprodurre il modo in cui lo dico io ma non sono certo di farlo correttamente :D

Comment: Io sono di Roma, ma non mi sembra che sia una pronuncia usuale. O per meglio dire, capita, pronunciando una parola con molte sillabe, di mangiarsene qualcuna (prova a dire velocemente “prestito interbibliotecario”), ma direi che sia un fatto comune a molte lingue e molte parole, in particolare nel cosiddetto “allegro”, cioè il ritmo del parlato veloce.

Comment: Ah ok, no per me è diverso dal dire una parola mangiandosi le sillabe, e soprattutto non funziona con nessun altro avverbio in -mente. Tipo non posso dire una cosa tipo *geneeente per intendere generalmente o *compleeente per dire completamente, in particolare  la m non pronunciata mi risulta del tutto innaturale. In "praticamente" invece mi suona normalissimo.

Comment: Mai sentito, ma non sono di Roma e vivo fuori dall'Italia da anni...

Comment: Ci farò caso. Per ora posso ipotizzare che, per chi dice così, “praticamente” sia quasi un intercalare (alla stregua di “nevvero”, “allora” e altre parole che qualcuno inframmezza al resto del discorso) e quindi l'uso frequente lo abbia un po' deformato.